# Div next another problem

Tags: css

I have one content div in body and inside that div I need three horizontal divs, one next another. I tried with float: left, float right and with fixed widths but it doesn't work.
How I can do that ?

Comment: Do you want to split that div into three parts? Did you try googling "three column layout" or similar?

Answer (score 1):

`float:left` should work fine. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2vyj/)

```
<style type="text/css">
  #box {float:left;border:1px solid}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="box">This is box 1.</div>
  <div id="box">This is box 2.</div>
  <div id="box">This is box 3.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* new clearfix */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

.clearfix div {
  float  : left;
  width  : 33.3%;
}



<div class="clearfix">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Clearing: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/